# Port collision error even though no jobs running on Hashicorp Nomad client

Tags: kubernetes, networking, consul, orchestration, nomad

As part of upgrading the Hashicorp Nomad cluster I started upgrading worker nodes one by one. I thought I will upgrade the master nodes later.

I upgraded one of the Hashicorp Nomad node from 1.1.2 to 1.3.1. The same job that was getting comfortably allocated on that node stopped getting deployed after the upgrade with the following weird error:

```
Scheduler dry-run:  
- WARNING: Failed to place all allocations.                   
  Task Group "job-test" (failed to place 1 allocation):
    * Constraint "${attr.unique.hostname} == eu-01-02": 1 nodes excluded by filter
    * Resources exhausted on 1 nodes    
    * Dimension "network: reserved port collision public=29999" exhausted on 1 nodes
```

When using dynamic port allocation strategy:

```
Scheduler dry-run:
- WARNING: Failed to place all allocations.
  Task Group "job-test" (failed to place 1 allocation):
    * Constraint "${attr.unique.hostname} == eu-01-02": 1 nodes excluded by filter
    * Resources exhausted on 1 nodes
    * Dimension "network: dynamic port selection failed" exhausted on 1 nodes
```

The node is completely empty, no process running there uses the mentioned ports, yet it says port collision! I've been searching the net for the past couple of days and couldn't find any clue.

If anyone has encountered this could you share how you fixed it? Or better how would I go about finding the issue, how do I debug such an issue in Nomad. I couldn't find anything in the Nomad agent logs running in the node.

I recently started working with Nomad after working with Kubernetes for around 5 years. I'm kind of lost here.

Answer (score 2):

Seem like a bug,
And fixed in 1.3.2
https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/releases/tag/v1.3.2